# How do I use navigationLink in iOS 16

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'me getting an error 'init(destination:isActive:label:)' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: use NavigationLink(value:label:) inside a NavigationStack or NavigationSplitView

```
.background(
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailLoadingView(coin: $selectedCoin), isActive: $showDetailView, label: {
                EmptyView()
            })
        )
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

1. `NavigationView{}` to `NavigationStack{}`
2. `NavigationLink(){}` to `NavigationDestination`

Example:

```
NavigationStack{        
...
.navigationDestination(isPresented: $isSame){
                        BackgroundView() //if $isSame = true, navigate to BackgroundView()
    }
}
```