# Share ViewModel only across specific views in NavigationStack

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios16, swiftui-navigationstack

I have a `NavigationStack` with three forms inside it and each form has a couple of screens. How can I share a form's `ViewModel` only across its screens without having to create an instance globally( inside `ContentView`). Currently each `ViewModel` is created whether it's used or not. Here is my code

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject private var pathStore = PathStore()

    @StateObject var formOneVM = FormOneViewModel()
    @StateObject var formTwoVM = FormTwoViewModel()

    var body: some View {

        NavigationStack(path: $pathStore.path) {

            HomeView()
            .navigationDestination(FormOneRoutes.self){ route in
                switch route{
                    case .screenOne:
                        FormOneScreenOne()
                    case .screenTwo:
                        FormOneScreenTwo()
            }
            .navigationDestination(FormTwoRoutes.self){ route in
                switch route{
                    case .screenOne:
                        FormTwoScreenOne()
                    case .screenTwo:
                        FormTwoScreenTwo()
        }
    }
    .environmentObject(formOneVM)
    .environmentObject(formTwoVM)
}
```

I have tried  placing each form inside its own `NavigationStack` but nested `NavigationStack` doesn't seem to work for me. If you got nested `NavigationStack` working or have other alternatives please share.

Comment: Do you really need NavigationStack with navigationDestination ? May be you should try to rethink your app. Wanting to absolutely use specific coding pattern is useless if does not fit the need.

Comment: Hmm what do you suggest? Creating VM instance on first screen then passing along as `ObservedObject`  with `NavigationLink` ?

Comment: It depends on what you do in HomeView and how you show Form views for VM A .

Comment: HomeView is just buttons to navigate to forms. Once each form is complete I return to HomeView . I was using navigationDestination because it was easier to append a route to path based on form state.

Comment: If I understand, you start creating a VM by tapping a button in HomeView which send you to FormOneVirwOne then push FormOneViewTwo,… when forms is finished go to HomeView and forget Form ? In this case the VM can be declared in as StateObject view one and passed as ObservableObject in subviews. So when back to home views it’s gone.

Comment: In SwiftUI the View struct is the view model already, you shouldn't use objects

Comment: @PtitXav Yeah, only problem is I can't use NavigationLink to programmatically navigate if I'm using NavigationStack as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72586394/programmatically-push-a-navigationlink-in-ios16) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75659442/how-do-i-use-navigationlink-in-ios-16) . I have to rely on navigationDestination which means I have to create instance at root level.

Comment: @malhal I saw your explanation [here](https://github.com/QuickBirdEng/XUI/issues/2) While I'd have to look into it, my question was on how to share form state across my `NavigationStack`

Comment: navigationDestination supports a binding now

Comment: @malal I tried that approach but I can't use navigationDestination inside child views because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74362840). So I have to create my state at root level?

Answer (score 0):

An example with a view model created only when doing into a specific form hierarchy. First level use navigationDestination, then navigationLink and binding :

```
class PathStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path: NavigationPath = NavigationPath()
    func gotoToTop() {
        path.removeLast()
    }
}

class FormOneViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var oneDone = false
    @Published var twoDone = false
}

class FormTwoViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // view one entries
    @Published var entry11 = false
    @Published var entry12 = false
    
    // view two entries
    @Published var entry21 = false
    @Published var entry22 = false
}

enum FormOneRoutes: Hashable {
    case screenOne
    case screenTwo

}

enum FormTwoRoutes: Hashable {
    case screenOne
    case screenTwo
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var pathStore = PathStore()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack(path: $pathStore.path) {
            HomeView()
            // here just to start first view of first model
                .navigationDestination(for: FormOneRoutes.self){ route in
                    FormOneScreenOne()
                }
            // here just to start first view of second model
                .navigationDestination(for: FormTwoRoutes.self){ route in
                    FormTwoScreenOne()
                }
        }
        .environmentObject(pathStore)
    }
}


struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(value: FormOneRoutes.screenOne) {
                Text("Form one")
            }

            NavigationLink(value: FormTwoRoutes.screenOne) {
                Text("Form Two")
            }

        }
    }
}

struct FormOneScreenOne: View {
    // model only exists while in first form hierachy
    @StateObject var formVM = FormOneViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("FormOneScreenOne \(formVM.oneDone ? "1" : "-") \(formVM.twoDone ? "2" : "-")")
            Toggle("One", isOn: $formVM.oneDone)
            NavigationLink {
                FormOneScreenTwo(formVM: formVM)
            } label: {
                Text("-> Form one screen two")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FormOneScreenTwo: View {
    @ObservedObject var formVM: FormOneViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var pathStore: PathStore
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("FormOneScreenTwo \(formVM.oneDone ? "1" : "-") \(formVM.twoDone ? "2" : "-")")
            Toggle("Two", isOn: $formVM.twoDone)
            Button {
                pathStore.gotoToTop()
            } label: {
                Text("Done")
            }
        }
    }
}

enum YesNo {
    case yes
    case no
    case undefined
}

struct FormTwoScreenOne: View {
    // model only exists while in second form hierachy
    @StateObject var formVM = FormTwoViewModel()
    @State var yesNo1: YesNo = .undefined
    @State var yesNo2: YesNo = .undefined
    var allDefined: Bool {
        yesNo1 != .undefined && yesNo2 != .undefined
    }
    @State var allEntriesDone: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("FormTwoScreenOne \(yesNo1 == .undefined ? "--" : (formVM.entry11 ? "+1" : "-1")) \(yesNo2 == .undefined ? "--" : ( formVM.entry12 ? "+2" : "-2"))")
            Picker("Choose entry 1", selection: $yesNo1) {
                Text("Yes").tag(YesNo.yes)
                Text("No").tag(YesNo.no)
            }
            Picker("Choose entry 2", selection: $yesNo2) {
                Text("Yes").tag(YesNo.yes)
                Text("No").tag(YesNo.no)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: yesNo1) { newValue in
            set(value: newValue, for: $formVM.entry11)
        }
        .onChange(of: yesNo2) { newValue in
            set(value: newValue, for: $formVM.entry12)
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $allEntriesDone) {
            FormTwoScreenTwo(formVM: formVM)
        }
    }
    
    func set(value: YesNo, for bind: Binding<Bool>) {
        switch value {
            case .yes:
                bind.wrappedValue = true
            case .no:
                bind.wrappedValue = false
            case .undefined:
                break
        }
        allEntriesDone = allDefined
    }
}

struct FormTwoScreenTwo: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var pathStore: PathStore
    @ObservedObject var formVM: FormTwoViewModel
    @State var yesNo1: YesNo = .undefined
    @State var yesNo2: YesNo = .undefined
    var allDefined: Bool {
        yesNo1 != .undefined && yesNo2 != .undefined
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("FormTwoScreenTwo \(yesNo1 == .undefined ? "--" : (formVM.entry21 ? "+1" : "-1")) \(yesNo2 == .undefined ? "--" : ( formVM.entry22 ? "+2" : "-2"))")
            Picker("Choose entry 1", selection: $yesNo1) {
                Text("Yes").tag(YesNo.yes)
                Text("No").tag(YesNo.no)
            }
            Picker("Choose entry 2", selection: $yesNo2) {
                Text("Yes").tag(YesNo.yes)
                Text("No").tag(YesNo.no)
            }
            if allDefined {
                Text("Everything entered")
            }
            Button {
                pathStore.gotoToTop()
            } label: {
                Text("Exit")
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: yesNo1) { newValue in
            set(value: newValue, for: $formVM.entry21)
        }
        .onChange(of: yesNo2) { newValue in
            set(value: newValue, for: $formVM.entry22)
        }
    }
    
    func set(value: YesNo, for bind: Binding<Bool>) {
        switch value {
            case .yes:
                bind.wrappedValue = true
            case .no:
                bind.wrappedValue = false
            case .undefined:
                break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't this mean the `NavigationLink` is always active whether oneDone is true or false ? So user can navigate to screen two without filling screen one

Comment: I just made a simple test to explain how to have only one active VM. I do not know what you want to do in your app and the logic you want. You can set the navigation link inside a test which will be only true when a screen is complete.

Comment: Yeah I understand, thanks. Could you explain what you mean by ‘set the navigationlink inside a test’ If it was the old navigationlink api I could just set its isActive property to match my form but that’s deprecated now.

Comment: @peeta: Made a little change in second form to handle conditional navigation and conditional display of text.

Comment: Hey Ptit, when I tried this approach I am getting error saying I can't use navigationDestination inside child views ( more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74362840) )